# WebView style debugging for a non-WebView application

Tags: android, debugging, webview

Aside from using `Log.i()`, `Log.d()`, etc..., I'm looking for a way, if possible, to debug code in the way one would debug a WebView.

For instance

> https://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/debugging.html

```
WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
myWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
  public boolean onConsoleMessage(ConsoleMessage cm) {
    Log.d("MyApplication", cm.message() + " -- From line "
                         + cm.lineNumber() + " of "
                         + cm.sourceId() );
    return true;
  }
});
```

The goal is to get access to methods like `message()`, `lineNumber()` and `sourceId()` that comes with the ConsoleMessage, but in a general sense. If it's not a built-in solution, any debug libraries y'all may know of would help as well.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [weinre](http://people.apache.org/~pmuellr/weinre/docs/latest/). It provides Chrome developer-like tools for debugging from WebKit browsers to browsers running on remote devices.

Comment: I looked at the weinre site and, although that would work fine for apps using webview, what I have is a camera app. I'm basically looking for a logging solution that could give me the line number and source file where the logging event occured, along with the message.